# Changing datetime format in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

I am trying to change the format of a datetime column from 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS' to 'YYYY-DD-MM HH-MM-SS'

input: 2023-04-12 07:15:10
script that is used in a select statement:

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a.time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')  as CHANGE_TIME
```

output: 0012-23-04 00:00:00
desired output: 2023-12-04 07:15:10

Comment: Are you using Oracle? Column time_stamp data type?

Comment: yes i am using using oracle the column has the date data type

Comment: If the "time_stamp" column is type DATE then where does this 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS' format come from? Dates don’t have any format until you convert them to character strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you applied `to_date` function to value that already is a date.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (time_stamp)
  3     AS
  4        (SELECT TO_DATE ('2023-04-12 07:15:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL)
  5  --
```

Query; I believe you should use expression from line #7:

```
  6  SELECT TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (a.time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS') you,
  7         TO_CHAR (time_stamp, 'yyyy-dd-mm hh24:mi:ss') me
  8    FROM test a;

YOU                 ME
------------------- -------------------
0012-23-04 00:00:00 2023-12-04 07:15:10

SQL>
```

Comment: On line 7, your format model should be `yyyy-dd-mm hh24:mi:ss`. You have missed the `24` and are only displaying a 12-hour clock.

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like you are using oracle sql and That the problem with your script is that you are using `TO_DATE` function,which converts string to the date. you must use `TO_CHAR` function instead.

EX:-

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(a.time_stamp,'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')as CHANGE_TIME FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7-bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored with any particular human-readable format (it is binary).

> I am trying to change the format of a `DATE` column

You cannot, it does not have any format that you can change.

> I want to display it differently

Then use `TO_CHAR` and pass the `DATE` value directly to it (**NEVER** use `TO_DATE` on something that is already a `DATE`; at best it does nothing and, at worst, it either raises an exception of gives you an unexpected result):

```sql
TO_CHAR(a.time_stamp, 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS') as CHANGE_TIME
```

> Why didn't `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a.time_stamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-DD-MM HH24:MI:SS')` work?

`TO_DATE` takes a string as the first argument and you are passing it a `DATE` so:

1. Oracle is "helpfully" implicitly converting the `DATE` to a string; then
2. you explicitly convert it back to a `DATE` using `TO_DATE`; and then
3. explicitly convert it to a string using `TO_CHAR`.

The 1st step is where the issue occurs as the format model in the implicit conversion appears to be `DD-MM-RR` and does not match the `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` format model in the 2nd step so your date is getting mangled swapping the days and years (and removing the century from the year).