# Change the format of a datetime column in PLSQL

Tags: sql, dataframe, datetime, time, plsql

I am trying to change a column that is supposed to be in utc + 2 time zone into it the data is instead written in this structure:
input: 06.09.22 08:43:37,139000+02:00
desired output: 06.09.22 10:43:37
I also need to take into consideration that because there gmt and bst some dates are like
06.09.22 08:43:37,139000+01:00 all the dates are stored into a column called change_time

this is what i tried but had no success until now:

```
CAST(FROM_TZ(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(LS.CHANGE_TIME, 'DD.MM.YY HH24:MI:SS,FFFTZH:TZM'), 'Europe/Berlin') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76968679/changing-datetime-format-in-sql for a better set of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach and for further help you can [check this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76968679/changing-datetime-format-in-sql)

```
FROM_TZ(
    TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(LS.CHANGE_TIME, 'DD.MM.YY HH:MI:SS,FFFTZH:TZM'),
    TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(LS.CHANGE_TIME, 'DD.MM.YY HH:MI:SS,FFFTZH:TZM'), 'TZO')
) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS UTC_TIMESTAMP
```